# Which non-separable topological spaces has an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open sets?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, separable-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a non-separable metric space  then I can show that there exist an uncountable set $S \subseteq X$ and $r>0$ such that $d(x ,y ) >r , \forall x, y \in S , x \ne y$ ; hence there exist an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open sets of $X$ . Now this is not necessarily true for general topological spaces : $\mathbb R$ with co-countable topology is not separable but any two non-empty open sets in this topology intersect .

My question is : Under some separation and/or countablity  axiom , can we say that non-separability of topological space implies the existence of an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open sets ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 notions from general topology that are involved here:

1. $X$ is called separable if it has a countable dense set.
2. $X$ is called ccc if every family of non-empty pairwise disjoint open sets is at most countable.
3. $X$ has countable spread iff every discrete subspace is at most countable.

You're basically asking when a ccc space is separable (which is equivalent logically to non-separable implies non-ccc).

In metric spaces, these 3 properties are equivalent (to being second countable, or Lindelöf etc.). In any space separable implies ccc, but there are quite a few counterexamples (ccc non-separable spaces) in general spaces, like large products $[0,1]^I$ where $|I| > |\mathbb{R}|$, e.g., or the co-countable topology (as you noted), or the one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space. The first and third are compact Hausdorff, but not first countable, but there are also consistent counterexamples that are close to $\mathbb{R}$ (ordered, first countable dense order etc.; Look up Suslin lines), so no obvious extra assumptions are enough to go back from ccc to separable I think.
(well second countable implies both but that's trivial).

Murray Bell constructed in [1979](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-01/S0002-9939-1979-0521889-0/S0002-9939-1979-0521889-0.pdf) the first ZFC example of a normal first countable ccc non-separable space.
MA + non-CH implies that all perfecty normal ccc spaces are separable, so in that case we *can* reverse the implication if we are willing to assume an extra axiom. ccc and non-separable spaces were a hot topic in topology for some time.

Comment: Is there any Normal, Hausdorff, First countable counter-example ?

Comment: @users Yes it's in the linked paper. It needs some work :) Under CH there is a compact one, even.

Comment: Wow , ok . What if I added Normal+Hausdorff+First countable + Paracompact ?

Comment: @users I can make (under axioms somewhat weaker than CH) an example of a compact (so certainly paracompact) Hausdorff first countable ccc (even hereditarily Lindelöf) non-separable space.

Comment: I see ... could you please provide the construction ... ?

Comment: @users It's based on the paper "a compact L-space under CH" by Kenneth Kunen. ( which you can probably find online). I replace CH by $\mathrm{CN}(\omega_1)$, which says that in any Cantor set the cofinality of closed null-sets is $\omega_1$, It's in my PhD thesis (an unpublished part). Kunen's space is already enough for your example.